# What is the primary method/meaning in “test” in Psalms 11:5?

Tags: psalms, body-of-christ

What does it mean that the Lord **tests** the righteous?

I know for some other Christians this seems easy for them to interpret but for me I am curious about the exact definition.  Thanks!

> “The Lord  **tests** the righteous, But the wicked and the one who
> loves violence His soul hates.” Psalm 11:5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yivchan יִבְחָן “He-Will-Examine” in [Tehillim 11.5] refers to the generous צַדִּיק human response to Suffering.

> Psalm 11:5 "YHVH [will examine] the righteous" (יְהֹוָה צַדִּיק יִבְחָן)

- If charitable living would automatically lead to immediate salvation or sinful lifestyles to immediate denial of Heaven, then selfishness (not the exercise of Free Will in performing God's commandments) would be the motivation for human actions.
- In Tanakh, both sinful & righteous humans are given trials for YHVH to observe their devotion to Him & their knowledge of Torah, demonstrated in [Ezekiel 4.12-15].

As stated in [Devarim 8:2] - “And you shall remember the entire way on which YHVH your God, led you these forty years in the desert, in order to afflict you to test you, to know what is in your heart, whether you would keep His commandments or not.” (וְזָֽכַרְתָּ֣ אֶת־כָּל־הַדֶּ֗רֶךְ אֲשֶׁ֨ר הוֹלִֽיכְךָ֜ יְהֹוָ֧ה אֱלֹהֶ֛יךָ זֶ֛ה אַרְבָּעִ֥ים שָׁנָ֖ה בַּמִּדְבָּ֑ר לְמַ֨עַן עַנֹּֽתְךָ֜ לְנַסֹּֽתְךָ֗ לָדַ֜עַת אֶת־אֲשֶׁ֧ר בִּלְבָֽבְךָ֛ הֲתִשְׁמֹ֥ר מִצְו‍ֹתָ֖יו (כתיב מצותו) אִם־לֹֽא)

Affliction is committed by angels who YHVH allows to test & witness the kindness of His human servants demonstrating their ability to reject evil, as recorded in [Iyov 1:8].

Allowing Evil to be placed in the midst of humans [Bereshit 2.17-3.19] is how our Father knows if His children will obey His instructions.

Comment: Well informed answer, +1